# SharePoint 2010 My Site Sub Site

Tags: my-site, my-profile

I've setup a mysite as a sub site of my main site. The way I did this was by creating a new site collection, an Enterprise My Site Host under my main site Web Application (http://admin-pc:16132/), in the Central Administration.

The web site address for this host became: 'http://admin-pc:16132/personal/people'
The 'personal' bit was in a dropdown with 'sites', and people was the bit I added.

I then went to 'Manage Profile Service -> User Profile Service Application -> My Site Settings' and set 'http://admin-pc:16132/personal/people/' as the site host location, and 'personal/people' as the location.

Finally, for the managed paths for the site, I added 'personal' and 'people' as 2 wildcard paths.

This works in a way that when I log into my site, and click 'My Profile' it takes me to my profile page with my site structure, so for my user satbav, it took me to:

```
http://admin-pc:16132/personal/people/Person.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ef%7Cfbamembershipprovider%7Csatbav
```

And correctly allows me to edit, however when I click 'My Content', it gives me an error:
Your personal site cannot be created because the managed path "personal/people" has not been created for this site. Contact your site administrator for more information.

If I add this to my manged paths, then none of it works. Even if I remove the previous 2 paths.

So, my question is, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,
Bav

Comment: I dont have an answer for you right now. However is this to be a production environment. If so do you expect to have a heavy user load? It is not a best practice to have mysites on the same web application as the main site. These should be separated. If not separated then make sure to have two separate content databases.

Comment: Ah right, I figured it out, seems I was just adding my managed paths in wrong. The reason I wanted it in the same site was for a)the URL continuity, but also, the client may have many more of the same site, but with differing themes, so if I had a central site, I wouldn't know how to style that up for different sites. Also, are all users always shared? Currently, I have setup Forms Based Authentication, unique to the site. Should everything be kept more abstract?

Comment: Then again, the 'My Site Settings' in the central admin still points to this 'subsite', so is it even possible to host multiple my sites that work independently of one another?